# Creation of separate home folder while installing two versions of ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory

I am planning on installing two ubuntu versions (12.04 and 14.04), along with windows in my system. I need to install two separate home folder for these two versions. (I would love it if one version of ubuntu doesn't see the home folder of the other one; but I don't know if this is possible). So to keep both the /home separate, I am planning to do the following. First I will install Ubuntu 12.04 by creating / (root folder) and /home partition (also a swap area). Next I will install ubuntu 14.04  by creating another / (root folder) and another /home partition(no separate swap, I believe). My question is how do I tell ubuntu 14.04 not to use the /home of ubuntu 12.04 and use the /home created during its own installation? Is it handled automatically (depending on which /home partition was created during which installation)?  Last time I did this both installation went fine; but I don't think my two /home folders were mapped properly to their corresponding ubuntu versions. Please provide your suggestions. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation process, Ubuntu will recognise the other partitions and give you the option to mount them, but unless you specifically set one of the partitions as your `/home` it won't determine it's a `/home` and use it. So, just to be clear, no Ubuntu 14.04 will not automatically use the `/home` from a previous installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But during the installation of ubuntu 14.04 the partition table will have a ext4 partition which is /home of previous installation, right? Do you mean to say that 14.04 will not count this one? I just want to make things clear.

Comment: Yes, during the 14.04 installation it will see the ext4 partition, and allow you to mount it, if you wish. But it doesn't have any way to identify it as a `/home` partition, therefore it will not count it as the 14.04 `/home`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply AJefferiss. You have been very helpful.